# PhpMyAdmin (use Amazon Linux EC2 + RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

How to show this Server Choice in PhpMyAdmin 5.0.1
i can't find filename 'config.inc.php' in v.5.0.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRP5N.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Also, post the contents of the dialog you mention, and include the image here in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The server choice dropdown comes when you have more than one server defined in the phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`.

By default, phpMyAdmin doesn't come with a configuration file, you have to create one manually or using the setup script. You can see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install for help creating one or reference the `examples` folder of your phpMyAdmin download. Specifically, in order to have multiple servers available, you need at least to have more than one server defined such as:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.1.2';
```

You might want to add more directives, but that would at least get you started.